# Strange behavior with ImageView reference and derived class

Tags: java, android, derived-class

I created some custom component based on ConstraintLayout in Android Studio. First I created base abstract class called MyButton where I do some basic stuff (e.g. get references to my components). Next I created derived class called MySpecialButton that extends MyButton, but I have strange behavior when I attach onClickListener to my Button, that is a part of my custom component, and call method that modify element (reference) that exists only in MySpecialButton from onClickListener.

In a present code, when i try call `setImage()` from onClickListener, this end up with log: `E/NULL: ImageView reference is null!` which means that from point of view onClickListener, reference `vImageViev` is null, however it is initialized in `inflateView` call. But when I call `setImage()` not from onClickListener but directly from `init()` method after `inflateView(R.layout.my_special_button)` everything is OK.
Also when I move `protected ImageView vImageView = null;` declaration from MySpecialButton to MyButton everything is OK.

This is my MyButton class:

```
public abstract class MyButton extends ConstraintLayout
{
    protected Context context = null;

    protected View rootView = null;
    protected Button vButton = null;
    protected Switch vSwitch = null;

    public MyButton(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        init();
    }

    public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        this(context);
    }

    protected abstract void init();

    protected void inflateView(int res)
    {
        rootView = inflate(context, res, this);

        vButton = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.vButton);
        vSwitch = (Switch)rootView.findViewById(R.id.vSwitch);
    }
}
```

and this is my MySpecialButton class:

```
public class MySpecialButton extends MyButton
{
    protected ImageView vImageView = null;

    public MySpecialButton(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public MySpecialButton(Context context, AttributeSet attr)
    {
        this(context);
    }


    @Override
    protected void inflateView(int res)
    {
        super.inflateView(res);

        vImageView = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.vImageView);
    }

    protected void init()
    {
        inflateView(R.layout.my_special_button);

        vButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setImage();
            }
        });
    }

    protected void setImage()
    {
        if(vImageView == null)
            Log.e("NULL", "ImageView reference is null!");
        else
            vImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_window);
    }
}
```

What's going on? What I should do to be able call `setImage()` from onClickListener without null reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are doing wrong super calls in your constructors:

This

```
public MySpecialButton(Context context, AttributeSet attr)
{
    this(context);
}
```

Should be:

```
public MySpecialButton(Context context, AttributeSet attr)
{
    super(context, attr);
}
```

Same for the other class. And move your custom init in a different function you call from each constructor.

Comment: Thanks! I move `init()` call from MyButton to MySpecialButton constructor and it's start working. I don't know why but this do work.

Answer (score 0):

thats because the **setOnClickLisnter** is called for the base class(which is ConstraintLayout) since you are not override it in the sub-class where the ImageView is not accessible.

try this:

```
public abstract class MyButton extends ConstraintLayout
{
    protected Context context = null;

    protected View rootView = null;
    protected Button vButton = null;
    protected Switch vSwitch = null;

    //...

    @Override
    public void setOnClickListener(@Nullable OnClickListener l) {
        vButton.setOnClickLisnter(l);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not working for me. But if I understand correctly setOnClickListener is not called for the ConstraintLayout class but for Button class. And if you are right why move vImageView declaration from MySpecialButton to MyButton solve the problem, even if vImageView is still inaccessible from ConstraintLayout class?